# Precompactness of a set in $l_p$

Tags: functional-analysis

I am trying to prove that the given set is precompact in the $l_p$, where $1 \leq p < \infty$, when $\beta \in (0, p], \alpha > 0$ and $\beta > p, \alpha > \frac{\beta}{p}-1$:
$$M_{\alpha, \beta} = \{x \in l_p:  \sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty n^{\alpha} |x_{n}^{\beta}| \leq 1   \}$$

I'm trying to prove this using $l_p$'s precompactness criterion, which says a set is precompact if it's bounded and the following condition is true: $$\forall \epsilon > 0  \quad \exists N \in \mathbb{N}: (\sum\limits_{j=N}^\infty |x_{j}^{p}|)^{\frac{1}{p}} < \epsilon \quad\forall x \in M$$

However, I am unable to prove that. Can anyone help me? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the operator
$T:\ell^p\to \ell^p$ given by $$(Tx)_n=a_nx_n,\quad x\in \ell^p$$ If $a_n>0$ and $a_n\to 0$ the operator $T$ is compact. Therefore  $T(B)$ is precompact, where $B$ denotes the unit ball in $\ell^p.$ Observe that $$T(B)=\left \{y\in \ell^p\,:\, \|(a_n^{-1}y_n)\|_p\le 1\right \}$$
For $0<\beta\le p$ we have $$ \|(a_n^{-1}y_n)\|_p \le  \|a_n^{-1}y_n)\|_\beta$$ Therefore the set $$\{y\in \ell^p\,:\, \|(a_n^{-1}y_n)\|_\beta\le 1\}$$ is precompact. For $a_n=n^{-\alpha/\beta}$ we obtain the first part of the conclusion.

For the second part consider the operator $T:\ell^\beta \to \ell^p$ given by $(Tx)_n=a_nx_n,$ where $a_n>0$ and $(a_n)\in \ell^{\beta p/(\beta -p)}.$  The operator $T$ is bounded by the Hölder inequality. Thus the composition of $T$ with $(Sy)_n=b_ny_n$ where $b_n\to 0,$ is compact. Observe that $$ST(B)=\{y\in \ell^p\,:\, \|b_n^{-1}a_n^{-1}y_n\|_\beta\le 1\}$$ For $a_n=n^{-\alpha/\beta+\delta}$ and $b_n=n^{-\delta}$ for $\delta$ small enough, we get the second part of the conclusion provided that $\alpha p>\beta -p.$ The number $\delta $ should satisfy $$\left ({\alpha\over \beta} +\delta\right ){\beta p\over \beta -p}>1$$